# Program type already present: com.Decoder.CEFormatException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, runtimeexception

I want to add a new publicity library (MobFox) to my app but when I try to run the app and install the apk to de device I receive the next error:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/marc.martinez/Projects/Android/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :core:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.Decoder.CEFormatException","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: com.Decoder.CEFormatException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate.run(DexMergingTask.kt:316)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTask.taskAction(DexMergingTask.kt:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: com.Decoder.CEFormatException
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: com.Decoder.CEFormatException
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:70)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.Decoder.CEFormatException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
    ... 10 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: com.Decoder.CEFormatException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
34 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 30 up-to-date
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.dev'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //Support Library
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:preference-v14:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    api 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'

    //Google Play Services
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.3.0'

    //Trackers
    api 'com.atinternet:Tracker:2.2.0'
    api 'com.comscore:android-analytics:5.7.1'

    //Utilities
    api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    api 'com.stanfy:gson-xml-java:0.1.7'
    api 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    api 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev181-1.22.0'
    api 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    api 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.5'

    //Publicity
    api 'com.yieldlove.adIntegration:yieldlove:1.2.3'
    api 'com.github.mobfox.MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:3.6.7'
}
```

I try to modify api by implementation but It doesn't resolve the error. I also try to resolve the conflicts with class CEFormatException as explain in this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes but the error remains.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but it's working for me now using the release they just did.

Try using:

```
api 'com.github.mobfox.MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:3.6.9'
```

Comment: Sadly I try what you proposed but I still get the same error. There is a duplicity between the two publicity libraries. Thank you anyway!